# VCPKG Pcl: Cannot open include file: 'pcl/io/vtk_lib_io.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vtk, point-cloud-library, vcpkg

I am trying to compile a project using Point Cloud Library (PCL) on Windows 10 using Visual Studio 2019.
I installed the PCL library via vcpkg (latest version 2020.07) both the pcl and pcl[vtk] version.
Vcpkg is connected to my program through its vcpkg integrate install function.
I am using the dynamic build in release mode.
When I compile my project I get the error

```
Error C1083 Cannot open include file: 'pcl/io/vtk_lib_io.h': No such file or directory
```

And indeed when searching through the vcpkg folder on my hard drive this file seems to be missing.
All other PCL headers and functions seem to be installed correctly.

Does somebody know how to correct</further debug this problem or install PCL in a way that includes all necessary files.

Vcpkg lists PCL as installed:

```
pcl:x64-windows                                    1.11.0#3
pcl:x64-windows-static                             1.11.0#3
pcl[vtk]:x64-windows-static                                
vtk:x64-windows-static                             9.0.1#2
```

Comment: I expect to see a pcl[vtk] in your listing

Comment: you are right I missed to include it: pcl[vtk]:x64-windows-static                                         VTK-Visualizations support for PCL. One question is why there is no dynamic build for it. Do you happen to know how to force dynamic installs on vcpkg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The visualization module in PCL is currently disabled within vcpkg since PCL currently does not support VTK 9.
You either have to use overlay ports to install VTK 8.2 or update PCL to use the PR adding support for VTK 9